# Interpret TeX commands and remove curly braces from \href{} content

Tags: bibtex, hyperref

**Context:**

In order to create DOI links I define a command`\doi{<enter doi here>}` as

```
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{doi:#1}}
```

**Problem:**

However this breaks with stupid input™ like `10.1007/1-84628-249-7{\textunderscore }13`. **Because it seems to interpret the underscore, but doesn't remove the curly braces**:

```
http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/1-84628-249-7{_}13
```

How would one define a command

```
\hrefcleanbefore{http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/1-84628-249-7{\textunderscore }13}{text}
```

to replace the `{\textunderscore }` with a real underscore (works by default) and removing the braces resulting in a working

```
\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/1-84628-249-7_13}{text}
```

(use of or hint to additional packages is welcome)

**Background:**

I have a great bibliographic tool which creates my .bib files but has stupid escapes for my doi field

```
doi = {10.1007/1-84628-249-7{\textunderscore }13}
```

I tackled with different options of preprocessing the .bib-file but they all lack the convenience of fitting in the build process. 
I don't think this is a complex tasks if one knows all low-level TeX commands, but all my tests seem to be inferior or conflict with the `\href` implementation.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{doi:#1}}

\begin{document}
DOI not clickable: \doi{10.1007/1-84628-249-7{\textunderscore }13}

HREF with \{\} not clickable:  \href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/1-84628-249-7{_}13}{doi:10.1007/1-84628-249-7_13}

HREF correct and clickable:  \href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/1-84628-249-7_13}{doi:10.1007/1-84628-249-7_13}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I load the `hyperref` package, the syntax `\doi{1234{\textunderscore }5}` works fine for me.  In contrast, `\doi{1234_5}` does not compile.

Comment: I don't expect `\doi{1234_5}` to compile, I expect doi to always be entered as `\doi{1234{\textunderscore }5}`, just to supply `\href` with a different version. (I think that is the main reason the software doesn't use a plain underscore).

Comment: Thanks for adding the MWE.  It helps to understand the issue.

Comment: Now that you have got an answer you will forgive me for saying that the *real* answer is either making your bibliography tool work properly or ditching it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `regexpatch` can be used to replace a string inside the definition text of a macro multiple times:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{%
  \def\tmpdoi{#1}%
  \xpatchcmd*\tmpdoi{{\textunderscore}}{_}{}{}%
  \href{http://dx.doi.org/\tmpdoi}{doi:#1}%
}

\begin{document}
  DOI is clickable:
  \doi{10.1007/1-84628-249-7{\textunderscore}13}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Read a bit into the package doc: (a) yes it is quite a multi-purpose command, but this is nicely creative: I never thought about the more general "definition text" when having the very special "argument" in focus; (b) note: the sibling package `xpatch` can't be used, although the doc doesn't mention `\xpatchcmd` being different from `xpatch`.

Comment: A DOI can contain more than one underscore. Therefore I am using the star form of `\xpatchcmd` of package `regexpatch` to replace *all* underscores in one macro call. Otherwise a loop needs to be programmed, which continues with replacing until `\xpatchcmd` of `xpatch` fails to replace something.